# Django: remove a filter condition from a queryset

Tags: django, django-models, filtering, django-queryset

I have a third-party function which gives me a filtered queryset (e.g. records with 'valid'=True) but I want to remove a particular condition (e.g. to have all records, both valid and invalid).

Is there a way to remove a filter condition to an already-filtered queryset?

E.g.

```
only_valid = MyModel.objects.filter(valid=True)
all_records = only_valid.**remove_filter**('valid')
```

(I know that it would be better to define 'all_records' before 'only_valid', but this is just an example...)

Comment: Can you show the code example, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#filtered-querysets-are-unique):

> Each time you refine a QuerySet, you get a brand-new QuerySet that is in no way bound to the previous QuerySet. Each refinement creates a separate and distinct QuerySet that can be stored, used and reused.

I doubt therefore, that there is a standard way to do it. You could [dig into the code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py#L544), see, what `filter()` does and try a bit. If that doesn't help, my assumption is, you're out of luck and need to re-build the query yourself.

Answer (score 18):

Although there is no official way to do this using filter notation, you may easily do it with [Q](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)-notation.
For example, if you ensure that third-part function returns a Q object, not a filtered QuerySet, you may do the following:

```
q = ThirdParty()
q = q | Q(valid=False)
```

And the resulting SQL conditions will be joined using OR operator.

Comment: You will need access to the third party code, but yes, that's a good solution. +1

Answer (score 6):

Use this function

````py
from django.db.models import Q

def remove_filter(lookup, queryset):
    """
    Remove filter lookup in queryset
    ```
    >>> queryset = User.objects.filter(email='user@gmail.com')
    >>> queryset.count()
    1
    >>> remove_filter('email', queryset)
    >>> queryset.count()
    1000
    ```
    """
    query = queryset.query
    q = Q(**{lookup: None})
    clause, _ = query._add_q(q, self.used_aliases)

    def filter_lookups(child):
        return child.lhs.target != clause.children[0].lhs.target

    query.where.children = list(filter(filter_lookups, query.where.children))
````

Comment: self should be query

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did in a similar case.

```
all_records = MyModel.objects.all()
only_valid = MyModel.objects.filter(valid=True)
only_valid.original = all_records

...

all_records = only_valid.original
```

Obviously this clears any other filters too so it won't be right for every case.

Answer (score 0):

```
original_query_set = MyModel.objects.filter(**conditions)
model_class = orginal_query_set.model
new_query_set = model_class.objects.filter(**new_conditions)
```

You can use the .model attribute on a QuerySet to get the model class, then use the model class to make a brand new QuerySet.

Comment: Please consider explaining why your code solves the op's problem

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for making me check the source code Boldewyn. So, it seems there's a new method right below filter() with the same parameters... called [exclude()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L827) (as of commit mini-hash ef6c680, for when it loses its line number)

> Return a new QuerySet instance with NOT (args) ANDed to the existing set.

So, to answer the original question:

```
only_valid = MyModel.objects.filter(valid=True)
filtered_results = only_valid.exclude(the_condition_to_remove=True)
```

Comment: `exclude` just adds another filter, keeping existing ones. It doesn't restore full queryset.

Comment: Oh, i see! I misunderstood the question then. Thanks for clearing that up :)